# PL/Python or Psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, plpython

I have a Postgresql 9.1 server, and I want to write some functions on Python.

There 2 ways: `plpy` or `psycopg2`. For me writing functions in plpy is like nightmare, a lot of "prepare" and "execute" methods... more comfortably to use `psycopg2`, but I care about efficiency.

Is it correct using psycopg2 on server?

Comment: Trying to use PL/Python is premature optimisation at this point. Do it in psycopg. If you find you have hotspot methods that are doing *lots* of round trips and moving *lots* of data, translate them to PL/Python or PL/PgSQL.

Comment: Funnily, the Python language has nothing to do with your question. It's a question of writing application code vs. writing back-end database code.   I write back-end functions all the time to isolate my database design from my data and processing thereof, exactly like an interface is separated from an implementation in application code.

Answer (score 6):

They are 2 different things. plpy (PL/Python) is a stored procedure language like PLpgSQL and psycopg2 is a client library which allows Python code to access a PostgreSQL database. With PL/Python, you will need to make a connection to the database and then call your function from the database. With psycopg2, you would write Python code to call the database. Unless you have specific requirements of writing a Python function that runs from within PostgreSQL itself, use pysocpg2.

Answer (score 4):

> For me writing functions in plpy is like nightmare

You've already made your mind up. Even if you use pl/python, any bugs in your code will be attributed to the language or its environment. After a while you will be able to abandon your pl/python code and re-implement it the way you always wanted to<sup>*</sup>.

The beauty of it is, that as Jim says above the two interfaces do completely different things - one running inside the database within a single transaction, the other outside as normal client code. There's almost no overlap between the use cases for the two languages. Somehow though you've missed that even while making up your mind about which is "good" or "bad".

<sup>*</sup>We all have our programming predjudices, but I'm not sure there's much point in opening a question with a bold statement of them.